# gRPC C++ Error code 14 : failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: c++, windows, grpc, firewall, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to implement gRPC server/ client for the first time using Windows Subsystem for Linux kernel and CLion as the IDE (on Windows). My code does not have any other bugs/ issues except this communication failure.

The following lines of code

```
    if(status.ok()) {
        cv::imshow("Rotated image", decrypt_img);
    } else {
        std::cout << status.error_code() << " : " << status.error_message() << std::endl;
    }
```

yields the following message

`14 : failed to connect to all addresses`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a kind of generic error message from grpc which can have multiple causes.
In my experience, it can be one of the following things:

1. Your server isn't running (either you forgot to call `grpc::ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart` or you didn't start your server application all along).
2. When running the server for the first time Windows Firewall should ask you if you want to allow your application to access the network (I don't recall the actual wording). You want to accept this, of course.
3. You have a wrong address specified in your client application (i.e. a different one than you have set in your server application via `grpc::ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort`)

Not knowing your actual server and client code these are just assumptions I can make based on my experience with grpc.